# Access to indexeddb from several javascript files

Tags: indexeddb

I'm try to write some simple chrome extension, which use indexeddb.
First.js file save number of clicks on some button to db, second.js show this amount to user.
But when I try to get stored data from database using second.js, I'm get 0 in any case.
Is it possible to access indexeddb from several js files?
Sorry for my english, thanks for answers)

Comment: That should work. Can you share your code so we can look for what might be going wrong?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, issue was in message passing between pages.